# SELECT INTO failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I faced this issue-

`SELECT INTO failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.`

In similar question ,one of the solution is that the `Ansi_warnings` setting must be on. When I do so, the XML operations related to the procedure execute properly and no error/exception is caught. But since I need to surpass the `Divide by zero` exception, I must set `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` in the same procedure. Since I had set the `ANSI_WARNINGS ON`, now I get `Divide by zero` exception.

Please provide a solution which could satisfy both the cases(execution of XML operation and surpassing Divide by zero exception) in same procedure.

Comment: Should be put your code !!!

Comment: There is no solution. Rewrite your code so that it does not throw divide by zero errors. e.g. Use `NULLIF` for example: `WITH T(N) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 2.0) SELECT 1/ NULLIF(N,0) FROM T`

Comment: This is the issue..Since the formulas are generated dynamically it could not be determined as to which input field would be the denominator.
For eg:The formula could be: ((a/b)+(b/c)) or a/(b1-b2)
Here how to find which field is the denominator..